# Since when has "the press" meant the news media?

Tags: etymology, idioms

For a long time, the phrase "the press" has been used to describe the news media. How long has it had that meaning? I have the impression that in the 18th century "the press" meant the printing press, a technology for making multiple copies on paper.

Answer (score 3):

According to etymonline, [the press](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=press) in the sense of  media is from 1921. This usage was gradually replaced by media with the advent of television:

> - Specific sense "machine for printing" is from 1530s; this was extended to publishing houses by 1570s and to publishing generally (in phrases like freedom of the press) from c. 1680. This gradually shifted c. 1800-1820 to "periodical publishing, journalism." ***The press, meaning "journalists collectively" is attested from 1921 (though superseded by media since the rise of television, etc.)***

Wikionary cites the following  1918 usage:

> 1918, W. B. Maxwell, chapter 22, in [The Mirror and the Lamp](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/press):
>
> - *From another point of view, it was a place without a soul. The well-to-do had hearts of stone; the rich were brutally bumptious; the Press, the Municipality, all the public men, were ridiculously, vaingloriously self-satisfied.*

Comment: "Freedom of the Press" was in common use by the later 1700. The US Constitution uses the phrase.

Comment: @ttw : You couldn't miss the point more completely. What evidence can you cite to show that that phrase meant the news industry rather than the printing press?